# How long do flag-bans last?

Tags: support, flagging

So, I recently discovered that three of my flags in the last week have been declined, and, as a result, I am under a flag ban.  I cannot flag posts for any reason, and, when I attempt to do so, I am redirected to a list of declined flags over the past week.  However, the banner informing me of the ban fails to list an end time or date for the ban.  How long do flag bans last?

Comment: Two of the three declined flags were the result of reviewers disagreeing with you.  The third one puzzles me: you flagged to close, other users voted to close, the question was put on hold, and the Community♦ user declined your flag.  The other close-voters chose a different reason, but this is not the result I expected.  If you decide you want to ask about that case let me know and I'll help you with links, but I'm not going to publicize your flags here without your permission.

Comment: @MonicaCellio, I haven't really looked at the content of the flags.  Can you, as a mod, do anything about that situation?

Comment: I can't override a flag block (that's backed into the code), but I can provide info for you to ask a "why was this flag declined?" question about that case if you want to do so.  Also, good news -- your oldest declined flag was on July 2, so that block should be expiring real soon now.

Comment: @MonicaCellio, that's fine.  I don't really care that it was officially counted as "declined", I almost have the Deputy badge anyway, and the ban will be short, so I don't really think it's worth making a fuss over.

Answer (score 6):

From the status-completed feature-request 
[Allow recovery from flag hellban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173878/352819), specifically [this accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/352819):

> Flaggers with a recent (past 7 days) flagging history consisting of at least 10 handled flags where >= 10% of flags were declined will see [a warning displaying the message "Attention: some of your recent flags have been declined - please review them before flagging this post!"]

Once you get past 25% the message instead reads:

> Too many of your recent flags have been declined - please review them instead of flagging this post!

This is where you are banned from flagging stuff.

Later it says (emphasis added):

> Depending on when and how those declined flags were cast, **this block could last for as little as a day, and won't ever be longer than a week**.

Answer (score 1):

According to the answer to [this Meta meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223859/reset-flag-declined-warnings-due-to-close-vote-burn-down) not more than a week. That may now be out of date as there are several other posts concerning extensions to bans.